# False hope after going for interview

Tags: interviewing

I have been to a few interviews, during the interview, I like them and they seem to like me.  All the questions asked, I give a favorable or positive answer.  When I send the 'Thank you for the interview', they reply to the email saying they will get back to me soon.

But after that, nothing. Not a peep. Not even a email saying 'better luck next time'.  What gives?

Comment: This question has been asked in various forms many times and there are many good answers that might help you. It can be frustrating when they don't even let you know you have not been selected. However, maybe asking them about their decision timeline before you leave the interview would help: "It's been a pleasure talking with you. When can I expect to hear about your decision?"

Comment: You are probably mistaking courtesy and politeness for genuine positive interest.

Comment: Also, sometimes interviewers act as your "buddy" hoping to get you to let your guard down and be more open and honest - you need to be careful around these guys.

Comment: Did you at least sent them a follow up email 1 week after? It never hurts to email giving thanks for the interview and that you are hoping to hear back from them. Don't discuss their inaction or anything. Just send a courtesy email and don't expect to hear from them again. Continue on with the job search. It's a cruel world.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may have missed the point.   When a hiring manager looks for someone,  the ideal candidate is the one for whom this job is the ideal move.

This means to keep you happy and motivated it should be the next step for you,  so the interview should be a challenge,  but one you are able to rise to.

People go to interviews and feel they handled every question easily and then wonder why they didn't get the job.

The reality is that the interviewer thought either that it wasn't happening on the fit and gave you easy questions,  or that you came across as overqualified,  so would soon get bored.

A good interview is one where it gets more challenging until they find your level,  and that's the level they want.

But regarding the silence,  get used to it,  it happens all the time.   They just don't want to deal with saying no to you in case you push on why,  and often this is a gut feel thing,  sometimes the planets just don't align.

Comment: Good answer, no one wants to disappoint a candidate face to face.

Comment: Also, it is a competition, you gave good answers, so did five other people. Only one gets chosen. People not chosen are virtually never contacted.

Comment: @HLGEM -  Yeah I liken it to the Olympics. You beat the world record! but you were running against Usain Bolt, and he's already done the lap of honour before you finished.

Comment: @HLGEM really? I don't think I've had an interview and not been contacted with a response afterwards. Maybe depends on country and field though. (in contrast, the application stage frequently gets no response)